# xslt grouping / restructuring from flat structure

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, structure

is there a way to transform a flat structure like:-

```
<recordGroup>
    <records>
        <fromcode>code2</fromcode>
        <fromname>name3</fromname>
        <viacode>code6</viacode>
        <vianame>name7</vianame>
        <viacode>code18</viacode>
        <vianame>name15</vianame>
        <tocode>code22</tocode>
        <toname>name23</toname>
        <fromcode>code22</fromcode>
        <fromname>name23</fromname>
        <tocode>code31</tocode>
        <toname>name32</toname>
        <fromcode>code31</fromcode>
        <fromname>name32</fromname>
        <viacode>code39</viacode>
        <vianame>name40</vianame>
        <viacode>code47</viacode>
        <vianame>name48</vianame>
        <viacode>code56</viacode>
        <vianame>name57</vianame>
        <viacode>code64</viacode>
        <vianame>name65</vianame>
        <tocode>code72</tocode>
        <toname>name73</toname>
    </records>
</recordGroup>
```

to :-

```
<recordGroup>
    <records>
        <record>
            <fromcode>code2</fromcode>
            <fromname>name3</fromname>
            <viacode>code6</viacode>
            <vianame>name7</vianame>
            <viacode>code18</viacode>
            <vianame>name15</vianame>
            <tocode>code22</tocode>
            <toname>name23</toname>
        </record>
        <record>
            <fromcode>code22</fromcode>
            <fromname>name23</fromname>
            <tocode>code31</tocode>
            <toname>name32</toname>
        </record>
        <record>
            <fromcode>code31</fromcode>
            <fromname>name32</fromname>
            <viacode>code39</viacode>
            <vianame>name40</vianame>
            <viacode>code47</viacode>
            <vianame>name48</vianame>
            <viacode>code56</viacode>
            <vianame>name57</vianame>
            <viacode>code64</viacode>
            <vianame>name65</vianame>
            <tocode>code72</tocode>
            <toname>name73</toname>
        </record>
    </records>
</recordGroup>
```

in XSLT. the upper section of the code is a flat structure which we want to transform to an another layer of structure ie 'record'. Please let me know any sample xslt for this.

regards

Comment: A new structure is created around each fromcode and tocode.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? Then see any example using `group-starting-with` e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="fromcode">...</xsl:for-each-group>`, the spec itself has one in the examples section https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples.

Comment: I able to generate the fromcode and tocode, but having difficulty with the viacode tags..

Comment: Tell us which version of XSLT you can use and show us the XSLT you have so far.